# Place image from Gallery on a Wall using ARKit

Tags: swift, ios11, augmented-reality, arkit, ios12

I have a list of images coming from server and stored in gallery. I want to pick any image and place on live wall using ARKit and want to convert images into 3d images tp perform operation like zooming , moving image etc.

Can anybody please guide how can I create custom object in AR?

Comment: What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: @JoshRobbins - I'm using this method to load image                                        let referenceImage = ARReferenceImage.init((image?.cgImage)!, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.left, physicalWidth: 100.0) .                                          But not able to make it 3d object

Comment: An ARReferenceImage is used for tracking. You will have to post some code

Comment: You can check out a complete solution on my GitHub - https://github.com/nativ18/ARInstagram

Answer (score 14):

To detect vertical surfaces (e.g walls) in `ARKit` you need to firstly set up `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` and then enable `planeDetection` within your app.

So under your `Class Declaration` you would create the following variables:

```
@IBOutlet var augmentedRealityView: ARSCNView!
let augmentedRealitySession = ARSession()
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
```

And then initialise your `ARSession` and in `ViewDidLoad` for example e.g:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //1. Set Up Our ARSession
    augmentedRealityView.session = augmentedRealitySession

    //2. Assign The ARSCNViewDelegate
    augmentedRealityView.delegate = self

    //3. Set Up Plane Detection
    configuration.planeDetection = .vertical

    //4. Run Our Configuration
    augmentedRealitySession.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])

}
```

Now that you are all set to detected vertical planes you need to hook into the following `ARSCNViewDelegate` Method:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) { }
```

Which simply:

> Tells the delegate that a SceneKit node corresponding to a new AR
>   anchor has been added to the scene.

In this method we are going to explicitly look for any `ARPlaneAnchors` which have been detected which provide us with:

> Information about the position and orientation of a real-world flat
>   surface detected in a world-tracking AR session.

As such placing an `SCNPlane` onto a detected vertical plane is a simple as this:

```
//-------------------------
//MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
//-------------------------

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Check We Have Detected An ARPlaneAnchor
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

        //2. Get The Size Of The ARPlaneAnchor
        let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
        let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)

        //3. Create An SCNPlane Which Matches The Size Of The ARPlaneAnchor
        let imageHolder = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: width, height: height))

        //4. Rotate It
        imageHolder.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

        //5. Set It's Colour To Red
        imageHolder.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

        //4. Add It To Our Node & Thus The Hiearchy
        node.addChildNode(imageHolder)

    }
}
```

**Applying This To Your Case:**

In your case we need to do some additional work, as you want to be able to allow the user to apply an image to the vertical plane.

As such your best bet is to make the node you have just added a variable e.g.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var augmentedRealityView: ARSCNView!
    let augmentedRealitySession = ARSession()
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    var nodeWeCanChange: SCNNode?

}
```

As such your `Delegate Callback` might look like so:

```
//-------------------------
//MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
//-------------------------

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. If We Havent Create Our Interactive Node Then Proceed
        if nodeWeCanChange == nil{

            //a. Check We Have Detected An ARPlaneAnchor
            guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

            //b. Get The Size Of The ARPlaneAnchor
            let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
            let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)

            //c. Create An SCNPlane Which Matches The Size Of The ARPlaneAnchor
            nodeWeCanChange = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: width, height: height))

            //d. Rotate It
            nodeWeCanChange?.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

            //e. Set It's Colour To Red
            nodeWeCanChange?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

            //f. Add It To Our Node & Thus The Hiearchy
            node.addChildNode(nodeWeCanChange!)
        }


    }
}
```

Now you have a reference to the `nodeWeCanChange` setting it's image at anytime is simple!

Each `SCNGeometry` has a set of Materials which are a:

> A set of shading attributes that define the appearance of a geometry's
>   surface when rendered.

In our case we are looking for the materials `diffuse property` which is:

> An object that manages the material’s diffuse response to lighting.

And then the contents property which are:

> The visual contents of the material property—a color, image, or source
>   of animated content.

Obviously you need to handle the full logistics of this, however a very basic example might look like so assuming you stored your Images into an Array of UIImage e.g:

```
let imageGallery = [UIImage(named: "StackOverflow"), UIImage(named: "GitHub")]
```

I have created an `IBAction` which will change the image of our `SCNNode's Geometry` based on the tag of the `UIButton` pressed e.g:

```
/// Changes The Material Of Our SCNNode's Gemeotry To The Image Selected By The User
///
/// - Parameter sender: UIButton
@IBAction func changeNodesImage(_ sender: UIButton){

    guard let imageToApply = imageGallery[sender.tag], let node = nodeWeCanChange  else { return}
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = imageToApply

}
```

This is more than enough to point you in the right direction... Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for posting code.This is really helpful but i want to convert images into 3d images and perform operation like zooming , moving  image etc                                Refernce App 
https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id1275654918?mt=8
I’m trying to make like this

Comment: If that’s what you wanted you should have been explicit in your question :)

Comment: Sorry I've edited my post and added link of reference app.

Comment: It’s ok don’t worry :) it just makes things easier for other people to help if your clearer :) when I get a chance I will take another look :)

Comment: I check on link you answered. I’m trying with that code but doesn’t’t seems help to me.I’m adding image on SCNode as
/** .  func  placeImage() {
 let image = imageGallery[0]
 guard let pointsPerInch = UIScreen.pointsPerInch else{return} . // height & width calculation using pixel 
 let photo = SCNPlane(width: widthInMetres, height: heightInMeters)
 nodeWeCanChange?.geometry = photo
 nodeWeCanChange?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
   } */
Now I want to drag this node anywhere  on screen. 
Any help would be really appreciated